# file type implementation like images, movies et cetera

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-type

i am wondering if there is any implementation for file groups / file types like the following:

actually i am implementing a file upload and i want to save the file type of the uploaded files in my db, so that i know how to render the different files. all my images like jpg, gif, png should have the file type IMAGE and should be rendered as pictures, all movies should have the type MOVIES and are implemented with a flash movie modul and all the rest as downloads. is there any implementation for this or do i have to implement the mapping on my own?

thanks for answers...

regards from germany

Comment: Can't you filter by file extension and adding to a group?

Comment: yes, but i wondered if there is an implementation for this doing the grouping automatically :)

Comment: I think it will be more meaningful if you change the question title to something like **Implementing file grouping by extension**. Anyway, have a look at this example, might give you a start **http://www.devcurry.com/2010/10/count-file-extensions-and-group-it.html**

Answer (score 0):

First think I've got that can help you - Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (aka MIME) types. You can get this info through MIME_headers like Content ID, Content Type, etc

Comment: hello and thanks for your reply. i already thought about mime types and registry keys, but i am searching more something like a group, so that all the pictures are in a group like IMAGE.